# How to open adb and use it to send commands

Tags: android, adb

I use ADT to try to make android apps, and use AVD. I know there is another tool called `adb`. I know it has been installed, and I want try to use it to send commands. Where is it? How to open it? Which button is used to open ADB in ADT?

Another question is where are the API documents? How to find it except on the website, like download or whatever?

Comment: adb is not a graphical tool, but rather a command line one.  So you would need to run it from a command line or terminal window.

Answer (score 47):

You should find it in :

```
C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Add that to path, or change directory to there. The command `sqlite3` is also there.

In the terminal you can type commands like

```
adb logcat //for logs
adb shell // for android shell
```

Answer (score 15):

In Windows 10 while installing Android SDK, by default latest SDK gets installed.
Platform List is part of Android SDK and the best way to find the location is to open SDK manager and get the path.
It will be available at: 
Android SDK Location: **C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\**
In SDK Manager, SDK path can be found by following the below 
Appearance & Behaviour --> System Settings --> Android SDK
You can get the path where SDK is installed and can edit the location as well.

Comment: **Android SDK location doesn't have to be at that location**. Mine is installed in `D:/Development/Utils/AndroidSDK`. The point being the SDK location is not fixed to the location you gave

Answer (score 9):

**If you have downloaded the AS + SDK bundle:** in Windows 10

C:\Users\ your User Name \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

Run adb.exe

Type adb shell.

Now able to access adb and the db.

Answer (score 3):

The adb tool can be found in sdk/platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
launch the SDK Manager
and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Also update your PATH environment variable to
include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
execute adb from any location.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is adb is used via command line. find adb.exe on your machine, add it to the path and use it from cmd on windows.

"adb devices" will give you a list of devices adb can talk to. your emulation platform should be on the list. just type adb to get a list of commands and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Android Documentation [Managing Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html)